# How to use Cocoapods in a Swift framework?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I am trying to create a new Cocoa Touch Framework for iOS in Swift, using some libraries from Cocoapods, but I can't have it work.
I know there are some opened questions about that, but none of them seem to fix my problem.

For testing purposes, I just created an empty Cocoa Touch Framework, installed Cocoapods and added the 'MBProgressHUD' pod.
Then, as [documented by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) ('Importing Code from Within the Same Framework Target' section), I imported the MBProgressHUD header in my umbrella header like that:

```
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
```

But when I compile, I have this error:

```
include of non-modular header inside framework module
```

I did set the 'Allow Non-modular includes in Framework Modules' setting to Yes, but it doesn't have any effect.

Is there any way to use CocoaPods in a Swift Framework?

Comment: I had similar problem. I ended up with copying cocoapods source code to my framework and making Objective-C headers public. I read at couple of places it could be done by help of modules but I was not not able to do so. If you are able to do with Objective-C modules do let me know.

Comment: I actually also tried to do that, but I need the AWS SDK, which uses some external frameworks, and I wasn't able to find the source codes for them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the solution, so I will let it here in case someone else has the same issue.

So, Cocoapods supports iOS frameworks since version 0.36, and as [it's said in their blog](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.36/), to use it in a framework, you just have to add this line in your Podfile:

```
use_frameworks!
```

After that, in a Swift framework, you don't need to include the .h files in your umbrella header, but you do need to import the module wherever you need it, for instance:

```
import MBProgressHUD
```

This is working for me, hope it helps!

Comment: I also needed to set "allow non-modular includes in framework modules" to yes in the build settings.

Comment: This does not appear to work if you need to support iOS7 and therefore cannot employ use_frameworks!

Answer (score -1):

Using '**Objective-C bridging header**' we can make use of Objective-C frameworks in Swift.

Refer the following, It will explain how to make use of **Objective-C** framework(For example [Parse framework](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide)) in Swift.

• [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32542017/1996294) 
• [Link2](http://codewithchris.com/using-parse-swift-xcode-6/)