# ios pod install gcm

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

Can't  install  google gcm with pod.
 Getting this error:

> [!] The 'Pods-project' target has transitive dependencies that
>   include static binaries:
>   (/Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GGLInstanceID/Libraries/libGGLInstanceIDLib.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCloudMessaging.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GoogleCloudMessaging/Libraries/libGcmLib.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Libraries/libProtocolBuffers.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries/libGTMSessionFetcher_full.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries/libGTMSessionFetcher_core.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Libraries/libGSDK_Overload.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_iPhone.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_core.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_UIFont+LineHeight.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_SystemVersion.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_StringEncoding.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_RoundedRectPath.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_Regex.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSStringXML.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSStringHTML.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSScannerJSON.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSDictionary+URLArguments.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_KVO.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_GTMURLBuilder.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_DebugUtils.a,
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_AddressBook.a,
>   and
>   /Users/mirzadelic/Projekti/project/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTMStackTrace.a)

I tried without `use_framework` in pod file, but still same.
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `use_frameworks!` from your Podfile and import any Swift libraries manually.

Source (my question): ['The 'Pods' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries' when installing GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910852/the-pods-target-has-transitive-dependencies-that-include-static-binaries-whe)

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting

```
CocoaPods 0.38.2 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods` ?
```

Then update your cocoapods by using `sudo gem install cocoa pods`.

After successful update try

```
pod update
```

This resolved my issue.