# Enabled the CloudMessaging service in Developer Console but get error (Podfile is missing the line: 'pod "Google/CloudMessaging")

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I am implementing google cloud messaging in my project, cocoapods dependancy is setup and my pod version is 1.0.0.beta.2.

I am using swift 2 and Xcode 7

when I run the project. inside console it prints this Log (**2016-01-23 15:08:08.754 gcmdemo[6598:4115938] You have enabled the CloudMessaging service in Developer Console, but it appears as though your Podfile is missing the line: 'pod "Google/CloudMessaging" or you may need to run `pod update` in your project directory.**)

**Here is content of my Podfile**

platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

target ‘gcmdemo' do

pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'

end

target ‘gcmdemoTests' do

end

I have also run ‘pod update’ in my project directory but this error is not solved. please help me to get out of this error.

I have implemented all the steps provided by google https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client?ver=swift

Comment: see this link  once may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910852/the-pods-target-has-transitive-dependencies-that-include-static-binaries-whe