# CocoaPods "target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries"

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, cocoapods, swift-framework

I'm trying to install a swift framework I found on GitHub along with the GoogleMaps, GooglePlaces into my Xcode project but for some reason when I try to install the pod file its giving the following error

> [!] The 'Pods-project1' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/Users/user1/Desktop/project1/Pods/GoogleMaps/Base/Frameworks/GoogleMapsBase.framework, /Users/user1/Desktop/project1/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework, and /Users/user1/Desktop/project1/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMapsCore.framework)

Here is my Pod File I'm trying to install:

```
#Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
#platform :ios, '9.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks!

target 'project1' do
pod 'GooglePlaces'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
pod 'PopupDialog'
end
```

Also here is the link to the swift framework that I'm trying to install:
https://github.com/Orderella/PopupDialog

I don't what to do, I've tried multiple things but non of them seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: May be this question help you.. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910852/the-pods-target-has-transitive-dependencies-that-include-static-binaries-whe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910852/the-pods-target-has-transitive-dependencies-that-include-static-binaries-whe)

Comment: I tired that but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 13):

It is because "Google-Maps-iOS-Utils" is not a dynamic library while you used "use_frameworks!" in your Podfile. Unfortunately, for this library, we need to install it manually for a Swift project. You can check detailed explanation here:

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/master/Swift.md

Answer (score 6):

I think i have found the solution, I tested myself through yourway and found the same error, So i gone through one by one pod installation, and its works and installed perfectly, but "**pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'**" is the reason for arising the error, instead putting this in your podfile, remove that and keep
this three under your target.

pod 'GooglePlaces'

pod 'GoogleMaps'

pod ‘PopupDialog’

Install them, it will install perfectly.

Now, in terminal when all dependencies installed successfully, run "pod try Google-Maps-iOS-Utils", it will started installing, then you would get options for like:

1: samples/ObjCDemoApp/ObjCDemoApp.xcodeproj

2: samples/SwiftDemoApp/SwiftDemoApp.xcodeproj

3: workspace/GoogleMapsUtils.xcodeproj

Which project would you like to open ?
select your number (eg 3) then press enter

Here you have selected your project and proceed accordingly. (y)
and you have done.

Comment: hey pod try Google-Maps-iOS-Utils  just open the project that it listed in number. when i select 3 it just open that Project only, doesn't install frawework.

Comment: What happening ??

Comment: Facing Frawework issue. as i have also raise an issue on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611599/cocoapods-target-has-transitive-dependencies-that-include-static-binaries

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? This doesn't solve the issue, unfortunately. Google posted a solution, you have to download it manually and import it to your project: [link](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/master/Swift.md)

Answer (score 2):

I worked with GoogleMap and i had this same error and it is just because of pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils' xcode gives this error. I removed **pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils**' and just keep **pod 'GoogleMaps'**. And it works for me.
Hope it would be work for you as well.