# Transitive dependencies that include static binaries using google map and clustering

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3, cocoapods, markerclusterer

My Pod file looks like this

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp

    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0’
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'
    pod 'Applozic', '~>3.8'
    pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
end
```

When i install pod with all this framework Stated it gives me This error

**[!] The 'Pods-MyApp' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/Users/Mad/Downloads/MyApp/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework)**

Please help me.

Comment: You can refer this solution,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611599/cocoapods-target-has-transitive-dependencies-that-include-static-binaries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CocoaPods "target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611599/cocoapods-target-has-transitive-dependencies-that-include-static-binaries)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying that the answers above are wrong, but I recently cd'ed into the project instead of the project-folder which resulted in the same output.

Answer (score -1):

You have to download the Utils repository locally and then import to your xcode project. A step by step guide can be found here: [Integrating with Swift projects which use 'use_frameworks!' in the Podfile](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/master/Swift.md)