# Can't import FirebaseStorage

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I'm trying to use FirebaseStorage and can't import it in my project.

My podfile looks like this:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyProject' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!


pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
//A bunch more here

end
```

However, when I try to `import FirebaseStorage`, I get an error saying the module isn't found. I've tried updating my podfile and rebuilding my project, but nothing's working. Also, all of the other Firebase services that are in my podfile can be imported without an issue.

How can I import the Firebase Storage module? Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you run pod install? Do you see any errors?

Comment: I get one error... `The 'Pods-MyProject' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries: //...etc`. Could this be the source of the issue? Do you know what the issue means maybe? Thank you!

Comment: What is your cocoapods version?

Comment: @tomerpacific it's 1.11.3 (which seems to be the latest)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CocoaPods "target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611599/cocoapods-target-has-transitive-dependencies-that-include-static-binaries)

Answer (score 0):

Add `platform :ios, '10.0'` to the Podfile. Recent versions of Firebase require at least iOS 10.

If there are still problems after that, the `Podfile.lock` should provide clues.